# grails run-app fails: declares and invalid dependency on parent profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3]

Tags: grails

Please, help. I have been trying to google this issue, but no luck.
I have created a very simple app by calling this command in unix terminal:
*grails create-app sample*
then: 
*cd sample* 
and then when I type in:
 *grails run-app* 
it fails after a while giving me this error:

*Download https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar*

*| Error Command [run-app] error: Profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3] declares and invalid dependency on parent profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)*

I never get to message where it suppose to say :
*Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/sample*

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ping grails.org server from your unix machine.  I don't think it has anything to do with Grails but with your server access and firewall rules.

Comment: It's a recent bug, as of 7 days ago.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9759#issuecomment-194826739 To stay in the loop, simply subscribe to notifications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known bug in Grails. No need to track it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the version of org.grails.profiles:web from 3.1.3 to 3.1.2
It worked for me.

Comment: basically, what I did, I have downgraded to grails 3.1.2 and I have successfully launched the app. no go with 3.1.3 version yet

Comment: Update, I have switched back to 3.1.3, created a sample app, and inside that app there is _build.gradle_, where I have changed org.grails.profiles:web from 3.1.3 to 3.1.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run with --stacktrace  (post here the result)

Verify too :

Version Java (jdk), Grails and if objenesis-2.1.jar is compatilhe with the versions.

Comment: As I have mentioned in a previous comments, solution to my problem has been found.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Grails 3.1.3

Version 3.1.4 just has been released fixing this along with some other bugs

Comment: yeah, just to back up this, here is the link which describes the current mater (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9759#issuecomment-194826739) . It has been mentioned in a very first comments  by **Emmanuel Rosa**. But for those who's keeping with 3.1.3, for the reasons they only know, **nayan kakati** solution works just great. I believe we can close this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9759), 3.1.4 fixes this problem.

Comment: possibly, will try this out, once I am back in developing with grails.